# Git warning: unsupported SSL version TLS v1.2: using default

Tags: macos, git, ssl, openssl, osx-el-capitan

I am trying to clone a git repository and receiving the following warning and error message:

```
Cloning into 'projectname'...
warning: unsupported ssl version tlsv1.2: using default
* Couldn't find host <HOST> in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying <IP ADDRESS>...
* Connected to <HOST> (<IP ADDRESS>) port 443 (#0)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <HOST>:-9838
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://<HOST>/ios/ios-app.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <HOST>:-9838
```

I am using:

- OS X El Capitan (10.11.3)
- Git client (2.6.4)
- OpenSSL (1.0.2e)

What's wrong?

---

**Update**: I created another user on my computer and there the cloning works. Only my user has the problem. Where can the problem lie?

Comment: What do you have set as the default protocol?  You should also add the host to the .netrc per the warning.

Comment: This is in my .gitconfig file: [http]
        sslVersion = tlsv1.2

Comment: I am not sure what other defaults can be set... How can I verify it? Do you have any clue?

Comment: Well you go from port 443 to port 9838.   The output literally tells you what the problem is, but its your configuration, so you need to determine what your default protocol is set to.

Comment: `.netrc` shouldn't matter as it's being used for failover. Check to make sure **1.)** `<HOST>` is available, **2.)** Your repo is available and **3.)** your creds are correct. Also, try again without the trailing slash, e.g., `https://<HOST>/ios/ios-app.git`

Comment: @Ramhound how can I check what port is set and where? Because I didn't do anything with the ports. I just updated the openssl and after it the problem appeared, but only for this repo. Is there a way to change the port number?

Comment: @SaxDaddy: my .netrc doesn't contain the <HOST>, so it is ok to use an IP instead of it. 1) Host is available, because I can clone the project from other computers. 2) Repo is also available, because I can do the clone. 3) Creds are correct, because I am using the same credentials as on the other comp.

Comment: In the meantime I've added the host to .netrc file and the warning regarding to .netrc disappeared, but other errors are there.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the following lines from my .gitconfig file:

```
http.sslverify=false
http.postbuffer=157286400
http.sslversion=tlsv1.0
credential.helper=cache --timeout=3600
```

I am not sure which one blocked my connection to the remote. Maybe the `http.sslversion=tlsv1.0`. I hope this helps somebody else too.